# How to add string at specific column in a file which is not a white space

Tags: sed, awk

How to add string at specific column in a file which is not a white space.

cat file.txt

```
abc
defg
xy
```

Now  I want to add string "test? at column # 8 of file.txt. But column #8 is not a white space then how can I add string?

It should be -

```
abc    test
defg   test
xy     test
```

Thanks

---Vishal

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to print the first field left-justified within a fieldwidth of 8:

```
$ awk -v s=test '{printf "%-8s%s\n", $1, s}' file.txt
abc     test
defg    test
xy      test
```

Comment: Not working. Please note that there is no whitespace after end of line.(eg-  after word "abc" there is no any white space )

Comment: @VishalPatel the solution does not require there to be any whitespace at the end of the line (aside from the newline character, obviously)

Comment: The beauty of this solution is that it doesn't rely on column 8 being just one tab away and it is easily adjustable to column 9, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty quick and dirty solution using `paste`, `yes`, and `head`:

```
paste file.txt <(yes test | head -n 3)
```

- `yes` prints endless lines of `test`
- `head` gets just the first three lines from `yes`
- `<(...)` redirects the output of `...` into `paste` as an input file
- `paste` joins the two input files together

Answer (score 1):

Using the sed command should help with this:

```
sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]*)/\1 \ttest/g' data.txt
```

Either run:

1. And created a backup:

   ```
   sed -i.bak -E 's/([[:alpha:]]*)/\1 \ttest/g' data.txt
   ```
2. Redirect into another file:

   ```
   sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]*)/\1 \ttest/g' data.txt > result.txt
   ```

Results:

```
abc     test
defg    test
xy      test
```

Info:

- `([[:alpha:]])`: capture alphabets
- `\1 \ttest`: return the captured group and add a `tab` and the word `test`
- `-E`: Extended regex option for portability.